# Выдает ошибку на 7-ой линии (IndexError: list assignment index out of range),объясните в чем ошибка, недавно начал изучение pythom

Tags: python, list

```
lst = list()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    lst.append(n)
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i % 2 == 1 :
        del lst[i]
print(lst)
```

Comment: В чем ошибка? Все вроде работает. Скиньте  кейс

Comment: Вообще такое возникает, потому что вы удаляете элемент из массива, но сначала берете длину из целого массива, что, очевидно, больше, чем с удаленными элементами

Comment: Спасибо огромное!Я уже сам допер ,что когда я удаляю элемент,массив изменяется и мой индекс переваливает через границу)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28883784/9210255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так

```
lst = [i for i in lst[::2]]
```

Соответственно, вместо `2` может быть что угодно, это шаг, то же, что остаток в данном случае

Comment: `lst = lst[::2]`